# Why does hello world print twice only and why is a's largest value 2

Tags: c, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int a=0;
    int rc=fork();
    a++;
    if(rc=0)
    {
        rc=fork();

        a++;
    }
    else
    {
       a++;
    }
    printf("Hello World");
    printf("%d",a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(rc=0)` -- that's an assignment.

Comment: Hint: `if (rc = 0)` is an *assignment*. Whenever you're stumped, step through in a debugger, or add more `printf` debugging statements.

Comment: it's largest value is 2 because of the if{}else{} statement.

Comment: @Meisterunner It's C as labelled.

Comment: It's worth noting that many compilers will emit warnings for this if you ask for them, like with `-Wall` when compiling. For example, clang produces " warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]"

Comment: If your compiler didn't give you a warning for this, you either have a terrible compiler or are you aren't using it properly. If you ignored the warning, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does hello world print twice only and why is a's largest value 2

To answer your question (after correcting your `(rc = 0)` vs. `(rc == 0)` issue), it may help to diagram what is happening in your code. For example:

```
    parent
      |
      a = 1
      if (rc == 0)
      +--------------- child 1
      |                   |
      else                +--------------- child 2
        a++               a++              a++
      a = 2               a = 2            a = 2
      Hello World2        Hello World2     Hello World2
```

In the parent process, you `fork` and then increment `a` with `a++` before your test of `if (rc == 0)` to give direction to the child process. The original parent sees `a++` again due to the `else` and `"Hello World2"` is the result.

In the first-child, you fork again, but the child-1 (as parent) and child-2 both increment `a++;` before dropping out of the conditional with `"Hello World2"` the result for both.

It appears you were attempting something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void) {

    int a = 1,
        rc = fork();

    if (rc == 0) {
        a++;
        rc = fork();

        if (rc == 0)
            a++;
    }

    printf ("Hello World %d\n", a);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/forkcount
Hello World 1
Hello World 2
Hello World 3
```

Sometimes a pencil and paper is as helpful as a keyboard. Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
      int a=0; //a=0
      int rc=fork();
        a++;//a=1
      printf("A before the if else");
      printf("%d",a);// a=1

      if(rc==0)// this was rc=0 it should have been rc==0
        {
            rc=fork();
            a++;//a=2
            printf("A inside the if");
            printf("%d",a);// a=2

        }
        else
        {        
            a++;//a=2
            printf("A inside the else");
            printf("%d",a);// a=2

        }
        printf("Hello World");// "Hello World"
        printf("%d",a);// a=2

        return 0;// always returns 0
```

as to why it prints Hello world twice I can't say from the code given but you must be calling main twice. if your language has the ability I would use a stack trace() ( not a c developer )

Comment: Although you've fixed the assignment vs. comparison there's no such thing as "await" in C.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the language specified at first.

Comment: How may `printf`s does it take to output a string-literal and integer?

Comment: `printf ("Hello World %d\n", a)` - 1 call.

Comment: ouch man no ssl on the webiste?
https://www.rankinlawfirm.com/ tisk tisk

Comment: The depth and merit of a man can be measured by whether he can focus on a single topic of discussion without resorting to ad hominems. It is equally applied to world leaders as well.

Comment: Shouldn't hello world be printed thrice because there are three processes? Am I wrong about this?